# Increment Date for every Thread in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jsr223, jmeter-4.0

I have a requirement to book an appointment, The value should not overlap.So I have to increment start time and end time for every thread and it should consider time from 9:00 am to 6:00 pm.I have written below Groovy code to increment the date. But for every thread I am getting the same value.Below is the log viewer ,where we can see that ,for all 4 threads the value didnt change. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def now = new Date()
log.info('Before: ' + now.format('HH:mm'))
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    def nowPlus60Mins = now + 60.minutes
    def nowPlus15Mins = nowPlus60Mins + 15.minutes
    props.put('After',nowPlus60Mins.format('HH:mm'));
    props.put('End',nowPlus15Mins.format('HH:mm'));
    log.info('After: ' + props.get('After'))
     log.info('End: ' + props.get('End'))
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; **properties are common to all threads**

So what you're doing is overwriting the value hence all the threads are using the same (last) one.

Consider switching from `props` to `vars` and you should get expected result.

Moreover, JMeter provides [__timeShift() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-dates-in-jmeter-using-the-timeshift-function/) so you don't even need any custom Groovy scripting

[image]